# How To make a resolution dynamic value in Multer Sharp S3 while uploading image to S3 Bucket

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer, sharp

Hello i am building a image upload function with `multer-sharp-s3`

Which is uploading a image in to S3 Bucket with resizing it on the expected resolution so according to my requirement i have to make the resolution numbers dynamic from database

```
const uploadS4 = multer({
    storage: s4Storage({
        s3: s3,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        Bucket: 'DIRECTORY',
        contentType: s4Storage.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        Key: (req, file, cb) => {
            cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
        },
        resize: {
            width: Helper.getPartResolution(),
        }
    })
}).any();
```

But its not allowing me to get resolution from the database
I tried getting it from Helper , Session but its not working

Can please someone guide me how can i get the Dynamic value for Resolution from database

As this function is developed on the Initialization of the controller so its not allowing me put any queries to get the data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like multer-sharp-s3 is not your solution if you want to assign width dynamically. You'd have to write your own custom solution, for example, using busboy. You'd read incoming data as a stream, check filename, determine the width, then call sharp and s3 upload manually passing the incoming file data.

What kind of logic is the width based upon? I'm thinking if the width is really based on the database contents or not. Could it be configuration data loaded during the boot of the application? Then it'd be synchronously available during runtime and make things a little easier. You'd still have to write the custom logic, though.

Answer (score 0):

it may be late, but in case someone would need it.

```
export const uploadMedia = multer({
    storage: multerS3(),
    fileFilter: filterImage,
})

const multerS3 = () => {
    const options: S3StorageOptions = {
        s3: new AWS.S3(S3Config),
        ACL: null,
        Bucket: config.aws.bucket,
        Key: (req: CustomRequest, file: Express.Multer.File, cb: any) => {
            try {
                db.media.model.getOneType(req.query.type_id)
                    .then((data: any) => {
                        if (!data)
                            Errors.notExists(["type_id"])

                        // @ts-ignore
                        options.resize.width = data.size.width
                        // @ts-ignore
                        options.resize.height = data.size.height

                        cb(null, `media/${data.folder}/` + Date.now() + "." + file.originalname.toLowerCase())
                    })
            } catch (e) {
                cb(e, null)
            }
        },
        resize: {
            options: {
                fit: "inside",
            },
        },
    }

    return s3Storage(options)
}
```